# I need to redefine script on Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with this script. Basically is working, but running on the same ranges for the whole sheets ("A4:V50") and I need it to run different ranges in each sheet.

Thanks!

```
function clearIPs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
    var sheet = allsheets[i]
    sheet.getRange("A4:V50").clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the script supposed to know on what range to run in which sheet. Do you have some sort of database, e.g. in a sheet that contains the range of interest for each sheet? Or do you want to run it for the whole datarange of each sheet?

Comment: That was the purpose, to set the specific range in each tab which is pretty similar in each one of them.

Comment: I assume the answer that was provided to you solved this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some type of Settings Objects. For example:

```
var Settings = {
  Sheet1 : "A4:V50",
  Sheet2 : "A4:B20"
}
```

And then in your code you can use this information like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  var sheet = allsheets[i];

  // lets get the right settings for that sheet
  var sheetNumber = i + 1; 
  var range = Settings["Sheet" + sheetNumber];

  // if there is no value for that sheet, lets add a default
  if( !range ){
    range = "A1:B20";
  }

  // now we can use that reference
  sheet.getRange( range ).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: great. Please mark the checkbox next to the answer so others can see it is resolved successfully.